# In plotly how to define colour and marker when adding a 3D trace?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I am running successfully the following plotly code to create a 3D plot:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='x', y='y', z='z')
```

What I want to do next is to add more data points to the 3D plot AND define the marker shape (e.g. as squares) as well as define the color. So I did the following

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=df2["x"], y=df2["y"], z=df2['z'], mode='markers', color='black', markers='s'))
```

but this leads to error messages, since `color` and `markers` are not accepted keywords. Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scatter3d.html) about this is very short and not comprehensible for me. I also wonder if I am confusing the functionalities of `go.Scatter3d` and `go.scatter3d`, since both are actual code with different functionalities. So what code should I do to define myself the colour and marker shapes for added points? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I asked eventually ChatGPT and it gave me the correct answer, this is what I need to use:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=df2["x"], y=df2["y"], z=df2['z'], mode='markers', marker=dict(color='black', symbol='square')))
```